# Como exibr duas mensagens usando MessageDilalog do Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, async, dialog

Como faço para imprimir duas mensagens usando `MessageDialog` do Windows Phone 8.1?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=391641

namespace Atributos_e_Metodos
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Desodorante desodorante1 = new Desodorante();
            desodorante1.capacidade = 10.37;
            desodorante1.tipoMaterial = "Plástico";
            desodorante1.esvaziarDesodorante();
            desodorante1.exibirConteudo();


            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }
    }
}

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace Atributos_e_Metodos
{
    public class Desodorante
    {
        public string tipoMaterial;
        public double capacidade;


        public async void exibirConteudo()
        {
            var dados_desodorante = new MessageDialog("Tipo de Material: " + tipoMaterial + "\n" + "Capacidade: " + capacidade + " ml");
            dados_desodorante.Title = "Dados da Classe Desodorante";
            dados_desodorante.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Ok" });
            await dados_desodorante.ShowAsync();
        }
        public async void esvaziarDesodorante()
        {
            var saida = new MessageDialog("Esvaziando o Desodorante !!!!");
            saida.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Ok" });
            await saida.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Windows.UI.Popups;
Using Windows.UI.Xaml;
Using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
Using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
Using SDKTemplate;
Using System;

Private Async void CancelCommandButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Criar o dialogo
    var messageDialog = New messageDialog("Internet não localizada.");

    // Adicionar comando e callbacks;  
    messageDialog.Commands.Add(New UICommand(
        "Tente de novo",
        New UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CommandInvokedHandler)));
    messageDialog.Commands.Add(New UICommand(
        "Fechar",
        New UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CommandInvokedHandler)));

    // Defina o comando que vai ser invocado por padrão
    messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;

    // Defina o comando que vai ser invocado quando escape for pressionado
    messageDialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;

    // Abra a menssagem
    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
}

Private void CommandInvokedHandler(IUICommand command)
{
    // Display message mostrando a label do comando invocado
    rootPage.NotifyUser("The '" + command.Label + "' comando selecionado.",
        NotifyType.StatusMessage);
}
```

Adaptado de [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208674)